# SQL Server 2008 DATETIME2 Format Question

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime-format

I am dealing with a date/time from Australia (I am located in the USA). I am unable to get the following string to insert into a DATETIME2 column:

```
2010/19/10 04:38:12.892
```

As you can see, it's formatted in `yyyy/dd/mm HH:MM:ss.MMM` format. I understand that the normal format is `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss.MMM`. What I am wondering is if there is a locality setting on SQL Server that I can change to get it to accept this format, or if I need to parse it and rearrange it myself.

**EDIT:** Just for your information, I have been importing a `mm/dd/YYYY HH:MM:ss.MMM` format string into the field just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the "locale" date format, I guess.

Some samples on how to convert here : http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Date-Timezone/Formatdatemmddyyyy.htm

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing `SET DATEFORMAT ydm;` before `INSERT`. Then `CONVERT(DATETIME,('2010/19/10 04:38:12.892'));` works fine.

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT YDM;
select cast('2010/19/10 04:38:12.892' as datetime)
```

And it will parse it correctly

**UPDATE:**
[I found help here.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/28/sql-server-introduction-and-example-for-dateformat-command/)

But I tried casting to datetime2 directly and it didn't work. I don't understand why you can cast to datetime and not datetime2. Perhaps a good question for SO. :)